# How to configure Juno to launch julia from specific conda environment

Tags: anaconda, julia, atom-editor, conda, juno-ide

I am working on Ubuntu 16.04, and I installed julia in a conda environment called py3 from [conda-forge](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/julia).

I have then installed [Atom](https://atom.io/), and then installed the package `uber-juno` through the software, but after the installation Atom does not find the julia installation, and gives me this error message:

```
We tried to launch Julia from:
julia
This path can be changed in the settings.
Details:
  /bin/sh: 1: julia: not found
```

How can I configure Atom to work with julia from my py3 conda environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Julia client for `Atom` will call `julia`, by default. If this default is kept, you can just activate your environment in terminal, call `atom` within this environment and easily start using Julia of your conda environment within Atom.

```
$ source activate py3
# or just `$ activate py3` on Windows
(py3) $ atom
# or `atom --new-instance` to force create a new instance of atom
```

If you have Julia installed in your environment `py3`, then you will be able to use it in Atom.